How to Refetch when changing query param
I am using Redux-Toolkit Query and I am passing arguments when calling a GET API. If I want to refetch and change the query params to pass how can I do it? Currently I am seeing in the documentation that you can only call refetch method but it does not accept arguments.
const { data, refetch } = useGetPokemonQuery({ pageNo: 1, search: "Pikachu" });

// Click next page:
refetch() // How can i pass next page no


The returned refetch function only refetches, i.e. re-triggers the query, with the same current args the query was last called with. You will need to update the pageno argument passed to the query which will trigger the query endpoint.
Basic Example:
const [pageNo, setPageNo] = React.useState(1);

...

const { data } = useGetPokemonQuery({ pageNo, search:"Pikachu" });

...

const nextPage = () => setPageNo(page => page + 1);

...

<button type="button" onClick={nextPage}>Next Page</button>

An alternative is to use a lazy query hook which returns a trigger function that you pass the args to.
Example:
const pageNoRef = React.useRef(1);

...

const [trigger, { data }] = useLazyGetPokemonQuery();

React.useEffect(() => {
  // Initial request when component mounts
  trigger({ pageNo: pageNo.current, search:"Pikachu" });
}, []);

...

const nextPage = () => {
  pageNoRef.current++;
  trigger({ pageNo: pageNo.current, search:"Pikachu" });
};

...

<button type="button" onClick={nextPage}>Next Page</button>

